# jquery - reset boolean to false on btn click

Tags: jquery

I've created a slide show where each image has a button that, when clicked, reveals an image underneath. The problem is, when the previous/next arrows (or navigation dots) are clicked, and the image is "reduced", the next slide's top image stays "reduced". 
Trying to write a function so that when the prev/next buttons/dots are clicked, the prev/next slide's top image is not "reduced". js & html below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id=hBtn]").click(function() {
    if ($("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced") != true) {
      $("[id=valueProp] img").animate({
        width: '-=1130px'
      }, 600, function() {
        $("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced", true)
      });
    } else {
      $("[id=valueProp] img").animate({
        width: '+=1130px'
      }, 600, function() {
        $("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced", false)

      });
    }
  });

  $(".dot, .prev, .next").click(function() {
    if ($("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced") = true) {
      $("[id=valueProp] img").animate({
        width: '+=1130px'
      }, 600, function() {
        $("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced", false)

      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" text="1" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" text="2" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" text="3" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" text="4" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  <span class="dot" text="5" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
  <span class="dot" text="6" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
</div>

 

<div class="mySlides fade">

        <div id="under" style="left: 8%; top: 30px; position: absolute">
            <video autoplay loop="loop" width="1136" height="612">
                <source src="GalaYc.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                <img src="gala.png" width="1136" height="612"
                     title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag">
            </video>
        </div>

        <div id="valueProp" style="left: 8%; top: 30px; position: absolute; opacity:0.95">
            <img src="slide1.png" width="1136" height="612">
            <button class="btn" id="hBtn"style="left: 80%; top: 45%; position: relative">&#8646;</button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
<script>
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        // Next/previous controls
        function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);

        }


        function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
            if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

        }


    </script>
```

Comment: `=` is not the opposite of `!=` in javascript.

Comment: `$("[id=hBtn]").click(function() {` has nothing to do with the HTML you posted.  Please review the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it is very informative

Comment: Please post a small sample of the HTML that contains the "images".  You reference functions in your JavaScript via the posted HTML that do not exist also.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($("[id=valueProp] img").data("reduced") == true)
```

Fixed...that was embarrassing. Helps to have fresh eyes on the code - thanks!

Comment: Could also be `if (!!$("#valueProp").data("reduced"))` coerced to a Boolean and given the fact that the ID property must be unique in and HTML document.